# What's the reason behind cabal (dependency) hell?

Tags: haskell, cabal

How does dependency hell happen in Cabal-install?

I read the following at [Cabal/Survival - HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal/Survival):

> ### 1. What is the difficulty caused by Cabal-install?
>
> The main difficulty with Cabal is otherwise known as 'dependency hell', in which the
>   cabal-install does not manage to install a desired package for a
>   reason or another, leading to large amount of manual work. As an
>   example of this difficulty, consider a case where the user wishes to
>   install packages A and B. Both of these work with package C, but not
>   with the same version of C.

I understand why this would make sense generally, but not with Cabal-install/ghc-pkg, because you can have multiple versions of the same package installed.
It's as if every version is an entirely different package, with how that in many respects the version becomes a part of the package name (e.g. `mustaches-0.1.0.0`) -- and maybe it really is for ghc-pkg (I'm not entirely familiar with it, but it would make sense).

Comment: \grumble{I can't help feeling cabal is just too slow, error prone, clunky and annoying. We're Haskell! There has to be a better way! Surely we could go with something more like `nix` (which is purely functional) but as portable as the Haskell platform. Even better, something where I can click "download" on hackage and it just happens, without clobbering anything. }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have scenarios like this:

[image]

Where both B and C depend on A. However, if they were installed at different times, they may depend on different versions of A. For example, A version 1 export `type T = Int`, but in version 2 it exports `type T = Bool`.

Only when you try to build D do you expose the problem that B and C were build against different versions of A, and you can't compare `T version 1` against `T version 2`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot link your program against those different versions of package C. A and B have to find a common version of C to use the same implementation of a certain function.
One solution to this problem is OSGi but requires stuff like Classloaders which can be used to load different versions of package C in the same process w/o conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

One way dependency hell happens is when several different projects you are working on interfere. While a single project has a solvable constraint set, two different project might not and since they're sharing a single package DB, there will be trouble. This variant of dependency hell is solved by cabal sandboxes.