# Wrong character encoding in simple Haskell code

Tags: haskell, utf-8, character-encoding

I have problems with character encoding in haskell. This simple program write wrong results. What I am really interested here is encode function which forces me to use ByteString. Application is:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack, pack)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (toStrict)
import Data.Csv (encode) -- cabal install cassava

main = do
    -- (middle character is polish diacritic letter)
    putStrLn $ unpack $ pack "aća"
    putStrLn $ unpack $ toStrict $ encode ["aća"]
```

It should print

```
aća
a,ć,a
```

but instead it writes

```
aa
a,Ä,a
```

This breaks my application encoding CSV. This happen on Linux no matter of my locale settings

```
$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8
```

or

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What I want to know is how to convert output of encode (Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString) to String so I can write it to file using e.g. writeFile function.

Comment: `ByteString` doesn't care about encoding, it just read bytes.  Have you tried using `Data.Text` instead?

Comment: @bheklilr I have added import fot toString.

Comment: You want to use `Text` instead. `Data.ByteString` will truncate any `Char` to a `Char8`.

Comment: Also, know that in the second case you are calling `encode` on a list of `Char`s, not on a list of `ByteString`s, so they aren't really equivalent.  I would highly recommend using `Data.Text` instead of `Data.ByteString` for this application.

Comment: @bheklilr So how should I modify this file so encoding works correctly -- I am insterested in encode function but since it uses ByteString I have added sample code showing ByteString dropping letters.

Comment: More to the point, `ByteString` outputs everything as Latin-1, which will result in certain characters not being valid UTF-8.

Comment: @Zeta I do not have much choice about data type. It is enforced by encode function which I use to encode to csv.

Comment: @Trismegistos Look at [Data.Text.Encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html) for functions to convert from `ByteString` to a proper `Text` encoding.

Comment: @bheklilr When I tried to use data.text haskell said 'HCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   _hs_text_memcpy
whilst processing object file
   /home/wolk/.cabal/lib/text-1.2.0.4/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-1.2.0.4.a' This library is colliding with almost every other library I use e.g. Data.String.Utils, cassava.

Comment: @Trismegistos Looks like you might have `text` and `bytestring` installed improperly (welcome to [cabal hell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869041/whats-the-reason-behind-cabal-dependency-hell)).  Try installing them both in a [sandbox](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes) and compiling with those versions.

Comment: @bheklilr What does it mean installed improperly? How could it happen I haven't done anything but called cabal install libname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStr` rather than `putStrLn . unpack . toStrict`. No need to go through `Text`.

`Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack` converts the byte with value n to the Unicode code point with value n. Don't use it on (non-ASCII) UTF-8 encoded text!

Edit: I see you say you want to convert the result of `encode` to a String to write it to a file. Don't do that, use the IO functions like `Data.ByteString.Lazy.writeFile` instead.

Comment: That worked but what if I want to convert bytesting to string or text to process it furgher?

Comment: @Trismegistos you should use the functions in the package `utf8-string`, the documentation is at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string, and I think it's installed by default with the Haskell platform.