# What is Cabal Hell?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am a little bit confused while reading about Cabal Hell, as the term is overloaded. I guess originally Cabal Hell referred to the diamond dependency problem, which was solved by restricting the build plan to have only a single version of any package in each build plan (two different versions of a package can't exist in a single build plan) as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870174/1525842).

However, the term is also used in various other contexts. Such as destructive re-installations, incorrect package dependency boundaries (lower/upper version bounds), inconsistent environments ... (or any other error reported by Cabal).

Particular among these, I am confused about 1) destructive re-installations and 2) inconsistent environments? What do they mean, and how `cabal new-build` solves these problems (is it just sandboxing like `cabal sandbox`)? And what role `ghc-pkg` has to play here?

Any references or a simple example where these problems could be reproduced would be very appreciated.

Regarding "destructive re-installations": If I am not wrong, GHC has a package manager of itself (`ghc-pkg`), and the packages are installed as dynamically linkable libraries i.e: `base` depends on `ghc-prim`, so if `ghc-prim` is removed it will break `base`, am I right? And since GHC only allows one instance of a package with the same version, `cabal install` might register a newer build of the same `(package, version)` such that it breaks the dependents of the unregistered package. If the above understanding regarding "destructive re-installations" are correct; how does `cabal new-build` help here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only meaningful use of the term is the one given in the linked answer. Related are the follow-on problems from having lots of different packages in the global database, which can make encountering diamond dependencies more common, requiring destructive reinstalls to resolve, etc.

The other usages of the term are not helpful and just mean "problems somehow involving cabal."

That said, let me answer your other questions.

1) `ghc-pkg` is not a package manager, but rather a tool for managing ghc package databases. It is used by cabal to register packages into databases, and can be used by end-users to inspect the contents of the databases. Think of it as part of the underlying substrate provided by ghc, not a competing tool.

2) `new-build` eliminates and replaces the standard notion of a packagedb entirely. Instead of saying that a db consists of packages and versions, with at most one of each pair, instead a db consists of potentially many copies of packages at any given version, each with potentially different versions of its dependencies, all of which are managed in part by hash-addressing, so marked by a unique "fingerprint". This is called the `store`. When you `new-build`, cabal calculates a build plan irrespective of any previously installed dependencies, from scratch. If a particular fingerprint (consisting of a package, version, and the versions of all its dependencies, certain flags, etc) already exists in the store, then it makes use of it. If it does not, it calculates it.

As such, the only "diamond dependencies" that can occur are the *truly* insoluble ones, and not the ones occasioned by having fixed too-early (due to already-installed deps) some portion of the dependency tree.

tldr; you write "since GHC only allows one instance of a package with the same version" but new-build partially lifts this restriction in the `store` which allows the solver to produce better, more reproducible plans more often.