# Vague 'Couldn't match expected type' error when trying to use ManagerDocks in Xmonad

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, xmonad

I am trying to add the `docks` command to my `.xmonad` config, but adding it results in a somewhat confusing type error:

```
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/dan/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:11:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘XConfig l0’
                  with actual type ‘xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Core.XConfig
                                      (xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Choose
                                         xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Tall
                                         (xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Choose
                                            (xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Mirror
                                               xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Tall)
                                            xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Layout.Full))’
      NB: ‘xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795:XMonad.Core.XConfig’
            is defined in ‘XMonad.Core’
                in package ‘xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795’
          ‘XConfig’
            is defined in ‘XMonad.Core’
                in package ‘xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-8c611bf8742b1b94190ab2fa494cb2a1cd3f8666db2ba536c81ae848ea043a6b’
    • In the first argument of ‘xmonad’, namely ‘(docks def)’
      In the expression: xmonad (docks def)
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = xmonad (docks def)

Please check the file for errors.
```

Here is my config file:

```
import           XMonad
import           XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks (docks)

main :: IO ()
main =
  xmonad (docks def)
```

I'm not sure what exactly has gone wrong here, and think perhaps I have messed something up during install.. though I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

---

Output of `ghc-pkg list xmonad`:

```
/opt/ghc/8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
/home/dan/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.0.2/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
```

Comment: It looks like there are somehow two different `xmonad` packages in scope. How have you installed `xmonad`?

Comment: I have recently done `cabal new-install xmonad`, but looking through `history` I have previously installed `xmonad` using `apt-get`, removing `xmonad` through `apt-get remove` has removed the xmonad login option (in Ubuntu), though I can still run the xmonad command, still resulting in the same error

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list xmonad` show?

Comment: I've added that output to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your build somehow depended on two different `xmonad` Cabal packages. When compiling anything, GHC stores, along with the type name itself (e.g. `Prelude.Maybe`) the *package* it came from (in the case of `Prelude`, `base`). You can see a list of packages available to GHC with `ghc-pkg list`.

The error message says that `docks` produced a value of type `XMonad.Core.XConfig` from `xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-50ceb56c2be27c58b715ff1418342ea50324c61ceef6f33afc6bf382abd08795` package (I'll refer to it as "xmonad 50" further for brevity). Note that `docks` itself is part of the `xmonad-contrib` package. However, the value expected by `xmonad` is of type `XMonad.Core.XConfig` from `xmonad-0.14.2@xmonad-0.14.2-8c611bf8742b1b94190ab2fa494cb2a1cd3f8666db2ba536c81ae848ea043a6b` package ("xmonad 8" further on).

This is the dependency graph of your build:

- your build

  - xmonad 8
  - xmonad-contrib

    - xmonad 50

Speculation of how this came to be:

- You installed `xmonad-contrib` and/or `xmonad` somehow, either from your OS repositories or by compiling manually. Your package database now contains xmonad 50 and `xmonad-contrib`.
- You installed `xmonad` again, and this created a different package version (xmonad 8). However, `xmonad-contrib` available to you is still from the earlier installation, compiled against xmonad 50.

This problem is known as [Cabal Hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925938/what-is-cabal-hell) ([another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870174/288201)).

What you can do next:

- Check that you don't somehow have two GHC versions installed. `/opt/ghc` is a nonstandard installation path, there might be other versions in your distribution's standard path.
- Investigate where the two `xmonad` libraries and one `xmonad-contrib` are installed. `ghc-pkg list` and `ghc-pkg list --user` might help here, or failing that, using [`strace` or similar tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420011/tools-for-showing-which-files-are-accessed-by-a-program) to see where `xmonad` looks while recompiling.
- Remove and reinstall packages so that you only have one `xmonad` and one `xmonad-contrib` depending on that. If you found the extra versions in the previous step, you can try `ghc-pkg unregister` them, and if not, removing the full package database(s) and reinstalling the needed packages again (together!) can help.

In the future, try not to install packages related to XMonad from different sources, and if you want to use new-style Cabal builds, check a tutorial specifically about new-style builds and XMonad (I am not using that so unfortunately cannot suggest any.)

Answer (score -1):

Your main function needs to be something like

```
main = do
  xmonad $ docks def
```